# Flip Text on Success or After a certain time delay with Jquery

Tags: jquery

How could I set up a function using jquery that would allow me to flip the text in a certain container say "#rndbtn" either on success of a .post form or after a certain time like 6000ms.

I am encountering a problem where the request is taking too long so certain browsers will fire off the call again after 60 seconds so I would like it to just flip the text to alert the user it failed after that time rather than tax my server again and again.

```
$.post("/sendreq", { arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2} , 

function(data,status,xhr) {
   if (this.console && typeof console.log != "undefined"){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(xhr);
   }

   if (data == "Error") {
        $("#rndbtn").text('Failed');
   }
   else if (status == "error") {
        if (this.console && typeof console.log != "undefined"){
                    console.log(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + " " +data );
        }
        $("#rndbtn").text('Failed');
                                       }
   else {
           if (type!=0) {
                     if (type!=4) {
                             $("#rndbtn").text('Sent Successfully');
                     }
                     else {
                             $("#rndbtn").text('Added to List');
                     }
             }
             else {
                     $("#rndbtn").text('Reset Successfully');
             }
    }

    $("#rndbtn").attr("href","");
 });  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function() {    
        //Calling after post
        var isSuccess = false;
        $.post('/ther/url/here', function(responseData) {
            //will get called after the Ajax call was successfull
            isSuccess = true;
            $('#rndbtn').text('foo');
        });

        //This will fire 6 seconds after the dom had loaded.

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(isSuccess === false) {
                $('#rndbtn').text('foo');
            }
        }, 6000);
    });
```

Comment: what if the success comes before 6000ms is there a way to add an if around a $.post request and say if longer than 6000ms switch

Comment: You could use a flag to mark the successful completion of the post, added above.